# Must the Minkowski sum of a Borel set and a *closed* ball be Borel?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Must then $A + B(0,1)$ be Borel?
Here $B(0,1)$ is the *closed* ball centered at $0$ of radius $1$.

I know that Erdos and Stone gave an example of a compact set (it is Cantor) and a $G_\delta$-set, whose Minkowski's sum is not Borel. But can we have an example with one of them being a closed ball?

Comment: Also [at MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121270/must-the-minkowski-sum-of-a-borel-set-and-a-closed-ball-be-borel)

Comment: Could you give the reference for the Erdos-Stone result?

Comment: @NateEldredge: P. Erdős and A. H. Stone, [On the sum of two Borel sets](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1970-0260958-1), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 25 (1970), 304-306.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks for the link. The answer by Tapio Rajala applies to $n\ge 3$ only. What if $n=2$? (The case $n=1$ has an easy affirmative answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is answered [at Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121270/must-the-minkowski-sum-of-a-borel-set-and-a-closed-ball-be-borel).